# 0 observations in Stata

Tags: stata

I've a file named 'test.dta' which consists of 217 countries with year ranging from 1960 to 2022. Now the file has been imported into Stata and declare the data as panel data by typing "`encode Country_Name, gen(cntry)`" and "`xtset cntry year`".
Now I'd like to do regression by typing "`xtreg unemp age_dr, robust`", an error occurred indicating "`no observations`", and this is confirmed by typing "`xtsum unemp age_dr`", which showed 0 observations in the file.

but actually for the variable "`unemp`" and "`age_dr`" there are nonnull values for many years in each country.

The file has been in long format for panel data analysis.

Comment: Check whether `unemp`  or `age_dr` is a string variable. If so, you need to `destring` it to proceed.

Comment: As you don't show and we can't see your dataset, you need to show more evidence, such as the result of `describe` for the problematic variables.

Comment: \datasets\test.dta
 Observations:        13,454                  Written by R.              
    Variables:            80                  
-------------------------
Variable      Storage   Display    Value
    name         type    format    label      Variable label
----------------------------------------------------------�__             long    %9.0g                 �..
Country_Name    str30   %30s         Country.Name
Year            long    %9.0g                 Year
unemp           str5    %5s                   unemp
age_dr          str11   %11s                  age_dr

Comment: Better to edit the question. But indeed you have two string variables there. so read the help for `destring`.  If that doesn't solve the problem you need to show examples of values of the variables in question.

Comment: Yes, you're right, both 'unemp' and 'age_dr' are string, so that is the root cause of this issue, right? Thanks @NickCox